# Updated Kodi version to Krypton v17 on Ubuntu 14.04 lts.Now my screen goes haywire when I move cursor, inside Kodi program while full screen

Tags: 14.04, unity, mouse, gpu-driver, kodi

Sorry for the long title, but i can't figure out how to put it into words.(EDit: it appears the words are "Screen tearing") So i updated Kodi files through the update notification. I wasn't expecting a version upgrade, so i honestly didn't pay much attention to the file details in the background. Krypton with the Estuary skin looks great! But now it's unusable, UNLESS i minimize screen. But when it's full screen, there seems to be some sort of overlay problem. As i move my mouse, the screen goes haywire. Blinking and strobing, like my cursor is creating static resistance.
The Krypton logo is always visible underneath all the windows, but the windows(Skin overlay or text boxes) go crazy while i move my mouse. When i stop moving the mouse, everything goes to normal, except only for 5 seconds, then screen goes black. I can minimize screen, and everything works perfectly. However, my computer then wants to hibernate after 5 minutes, regardless of player action. The video itself will have major ghosting. Like instead of linear frames, the frames will pile up on top of each other. I'll go into settings field, then back out to home page, and the screen shows settings page overlapping home page etc. Also, i tried going back to confluence, but that didn't help. I've tried a few display changes inside Kodi settings, but now I'm wondering if it's a compatibility issue with something in Ubuntu machine. Could be that i need to do a fresh, manual install of the new version. But I'm hoping maybe there's a setting I'm not thinking of.

Ubuntu 14.04 lts, Krypton 17.0, Intel i7, 16gb ram, Msi r9 280x gaming video card, KERNEL 3.13.0-108-generic, Graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD TAHITI

Comment: There's some troubleshooting info related to video issues with Kodi to be found [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/Linux_FAQ#Video_tearing_on_Nvidia_GPUs)

Answer (score 1):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi

nb. Please make sure to remove the other PPA's for Kodi, as they will conflict with this one.
How to return to Kodi 16 after Kodi 17 update

Comment: http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Downgrading_to_a_stable_version_from_a_development_version

Answer (score 0):

Kodi v17 Krypton does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

- Kodi does not support hardware acceleration on Ubuntu 14.04
- Kodi does not support Ubuntu 14.04's version of Indigo

Comment: Please consider expanding on your answer with more information. This will help others with similar issues make informed decisions.